# TypeError: glob pattern string required

Tags: gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I'm trying to compile `sass` using `gulp-ruby-sass` but I'm getting `TypeError: glob pattern string required`.

This is what my `gulpfile.js` looks like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

var paths = {
    sassSrcPath: ['Content/css/**/*.scss'],
    sassDestPath: ['build/css/'],
    sassImportsPath: ['Content/styleguide/']
};

// Styles Task
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.sassSrcPath)
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'compressed',
            loadPath: [paths.sassImportsPath]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.sassDestPath));
});

// Watch Task
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.sassSrcPath, ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
├── Content
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── partials
│   │   │   └─_icons.scss
│   │   ├── main.css.scss
│   │   └── styleguide.css.scss
│   └── styleguide
│       ├── css
│       │   └─ vendor
│       │      └─ // Bunch of other folders that contain .sass files
│       └── // Other .sass files
└── gulpfile.js
```

I'm fresh new to Gulp and I haven't used Grunt either so excuse me if I made a trivial mistake.

Comment: in my case even after run the sass directly, also this sassDestPath: ['build/css/'] generate error "Error: Invalid output folder" so I change it to 'build/css/' and that's fix the issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass), it doesn't seem like you're supposed to pipe into `gulp-ruby-sass`, but rather call it directly like that :

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return sass(paths.sassSrcPath, {
            style: 'compressed',
            loadPath: [paths.sassImportsPath]
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.sassDestPath));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I watched the video tutorial where gulp-ruby-sass was used the way I used it so I didn't even look at the official docs.