# Gulp.js TypeError: glob pattern string required

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-gulp-js-on-your-vps) to set up gulp.js on Ubuntu. However, when I run `gulp styles` in the terminal I get the 'TypeError: glob pattern string required' error. I'm a complete gulp noob - could anyone point me in the right direction?

My `gulpfile.js` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

My file directory:

[image: file pathing]

**Edit:**

I tried this in my `gulp.js` file:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return sass('sass/*.scss', {
      style: 'expanded'
    })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

and received this error output:

[image]

Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: A direct answer for your question is already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967345/typeerror-glob-pattern-string-required?rq=1. But as a gulp-noob, I tried to teach you to fish a bit ;) Hope it helps.

Comment: I saw that question/answer but could not (and still do not) understand how to apply it to my specific gulp.js file/file structure. Sorry - as I say, I'm very new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't a direct fix to my initial question, here is how I got the most basic gulp script to work (almost all of the tutorials went above and beyond what I wanted so I had to figure it out myself through trial and error).

Here is my `gulp.js` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('js/dev/main.js')
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});
```

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Basically what it's doing is utilizing this gulp [babel.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel/) plugin and converting my (ECMA6) javascript in the `js/dev/main.js` to ECMA5 javascript in the form of a `/js/main.js` file it creates upon entering `gulp` into the terminal. From here, add/remove your own [gulp plugins](http://gulpjs.com/plugins/) at will. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The error being thrown by gulp is related to a `post-css` npm module. Since you are using sass, I'm not sure why this is there. Try removing it and post your `package.json` file.

According to the docs, you don't want to use `pipe` in that first declaration according to the gulp-ruby-sass. Try this instead:

```
// Styles Task
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return sass(paths.sassSrcPath, {
            style: 'compressed',
            loadPath: [paths.sassImportsPath]
        })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.sassDestPath));
});
```

### More in-depth info

Use [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) instead of gulp-ruby-sass. It's a much faster, better supported version of Sass at this point in it's dev cycle.

This is how I usually use gulp-sass in a `styles` build task (based off of Yeoman generator [gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp#readme)):

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass.sync({
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      precision: 10,
      includePaths: ['.']
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 1 version']}))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

It's similar to yours but it outputs sourcemaps, which are super helpful when you are debugging compressed code. You'd have to add [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) to your `package.json` to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm pretty sure I'll take you up on your advice when I get the hang of Gulp a little more. For now, however, I'd like to just get it firing a basic script. Any chance you could help me fix any issues in my current gulp.js file?

Comment: @VoA - updated answer with a quick fix you can try. You don't want to use pipe in the first declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the help - you nudged me in the right direction. I have updated my question with an answer should anyone else stumble upon it. Basically I simplified the whole situation to get gulp to fire a basic task (babel.js) to see if I could get it working.

Comment: Good to hear - curious to see your final solution.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue in past. You need to use sass plugin directly ( instead of using with pipe)

Comment: Could you please show me how to write that into my gulp.js file? Having a point of reference would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Please look into DOC here , You have to use `gulp-ruby-sass` rather then using directly :-

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return sass(paths.sassSrcPath, {
            style: 'compressed',
            loadPath: [paths.sassImportsPath]
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.sassDestPath));
});
```

It may help you.

Comment: I tried to apply this solution but it threw another error. Please see the edit to my original post for details. Basically - I'm not sure how to apply this solution to my situation.